# How to change the left value using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two classes:

`offcanvas-menu-selector`   and `sub-navigation`. By default, the left value of `sub-navigation` is `left:-250px`. I want to change this value to be `left:0px` upon clicking `offcanvas-menu-selector`

I tried the following:

```
$('.offcanvas-menu-selector').onclick(function(){
    $('.sub-navigation').css({left: 0, position:'absolute'});
});
```

But it is not working. Gives me a error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionjquery.js:33 (anonymous function)jquery.min.js:2 jjquery.min.js:2 k.fireWithjquery.min.js:2 m.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2 J`

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think you need the curly braces {}

Comment: It gives me an error without it.

Comment: You *do* need the curly braces.

Comment: Ok...still learning.

Comment: use click, not onclick.

Comment: I believe that the usual method for changing these things is to toggle a class though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.offcanvas-menu-selector').click(function(){
    $('.sub-navigation').css({left: 0, position:'absolute'});
});
```

**Explanation**

`onclick` doesn't exist in jQuery. It's `click` you're after.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

### EDIT

Although this now works, and you're successfully setting CSS attributes with javascript/jQuery, I wouldn't recommend it. I prefer to keep function (js), style (css) and markup (html) as separate as possible.

With that said, I'd prefer this approach:

**CSS:**

```
.myClass
{
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.offcanvas-menu-selector').click(function(){
    $('.sub-navigation').toggleClass('myClass');
});
```

**Explanation**

You're now simply using jQuery to toggle a class, but have all the properties of this class in your stylesheet. Much neater. Defining styles in-line/in jQuery will more than likely cause you a headache down the line. This approach also addresses the problem you've raised in your comment.

Comment: Oh My bad! Thanks for it :) Also, how can I remove the 0px ro -250px if I click it again?

Comment: Well I wouldn't do that in javascript at all, I'll edit the answer now to elaborate on why....

Comment: THanks for the advice. It helped a lot. I would like to ask one more thing. How can I make the position of a title fixed as we scroll down and when meets with another title, the first one goes up and second one is fixed at the top. And vice-versa on scrolling up?

Comment: No probs. http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/ If you need any further expansion on this please ask another separate question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `onclick` function in jQuery. Rather, you can use the `.click()` method, or, if there's a chance your element isn't in the page on load, you can use `.on()` and delegate the click event:

```
$('body').on("click",".offcanvas-menu-selector", (function(){
    $('.sub-navigation').css({left: 0, position:'absolute'});
});
```

Comment: Have my upvote for mentioning `on`. Very useful indeed.